# How can I fake browser POST request with NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, post

I want to send a POST request to `example.com` just like browser does. There's a form on `example.com` that you submit and it gives you the information for the subset you selected.

When I submit it with browser it shows the information. And here are the page headers in Chrome:
[image: Chrome headers]

But when I try to send a request on my own from `myserver.com` like this:

```
request.post({
    url: 'http://example.com',
    json : false,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        //'POST /study/?id=11 HTTP/1.1':'',
        'Host':'example.com',
        'Connection':'keep-alive',
        'Content-Length':'34',
        'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
        'Origin':'http://example.com',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36',
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Referer':'http://example.com',
        //'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
        'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6',
        'Cookie':'ssd_num=1m99jeo61eb4srduha9osqr9p2',
        'X-Compress':'null',
    },
    formData: {
        'tmtblTip':'0',
        'showKla':'10%E0',
        'sbShRKl':'1'
    },
    encoding: null
}, (err, res, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error:', err);
    } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
        console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
    } else {
        // data is already parsed as JSON:
        //let bodyWithCorrectEncoding = iconv.decode(data, 'win1251');
        let bodyWithCorrectEncoding = toUtf(data, 'utf8','win1251');
        console.log(bodyWithCorrectEncoding);
    }
});
```

When I do this it returns the webpage, but it says `There's no such subset`.

Can you please tell me what is the difference between these requests (mine and browser)?

Comment: In the absence of a minimal, complete, verifiable example, there is no way for us to know. Look in the logs of the server?

Comment: The problem is that I don't own `example.com`. I'm trying to make an API for it

Comment: I'd suggest dummying up your own server, possibly with Node, and look at the incoming requests made by your browser to it, vs by your JS client, and see how (if at all) they're different. You're probably creating trouble for yourself by trying to manually supply most of those headers, though `Cookie` is almost certainly needed!

Comment: I disabled cookies in chrome. Deleted all the cache but `example.com` was still giving me the subset through browser.

Comment: Disabling cookies is probably guaranteeing failure. Have you tried my suggestion of making your own dumb, logging server? You can use Chrome's "copy request as cURL" to give you something you can lightly modify to point at your own server.

Comment: No, I haven't yet. I will try it later, but for now I tracked all post requests that website made to itself with Postman Interceptor. And I might have found the problem. The request has value 10� in it. I tried resending the request but it ended up with `No such subset`. Is it possible that the problem is in the server's bad encoding?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154556/discussion-between-furetur-phyarell-and-ed).